# Ilnumeric Plotcube custom axis scaling

Tags: plot, normal-distribution, ilnumerics, weibull

I am very new to Ilnumeric. I see two scaling modes for the axis in a plot: log and linear.

Is there any easy (or complicated) way to get the axis and data) to be displayed in an arbitrary way (in 2D)?
For example, I want to display the data on a nonlinear axis like a normal probability plot (where the y-axis is scaled with the error function = inverted cumulative distribution function). This is one example, I can think of various other transformations, like the Weibull plot.

I am familiar with matplotlib in python. In matplotlib it is possible to define custom axis transformations as discussed above. Do i need to set up my own "plot scene graph" or is there any way to do it with the Plotcube class?

Comment: There is no other scaling than linear and log. You can always apply your transformation function to your data and handle the tick labeling manually, though.

Comment: Yes, thanks. i just found the possibility for custom tick labeling and positioning (+grid positioning). So i need to position the ticks for the given transformation and transform the data accordingly